# Error while updating property 'fill' of a view managed by: RNSVGLine

Tags: view, linechart, fill

i am facing a issue very wird. I am trying to build a chart in react native, for that i use react-native-chart-kit but when i past one example for de documentaion of the library and build it he appear me this error : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPZyX.png)

My Dependicies:

[Dependicies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khp6O.png)

This is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {
    LineChart,
    BarChart,
    PieChart,
    ProgressChart,
    ContributionGraph,
    StackedBarChart
} from 'react-native-chart-kit'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Bezier Line Chart
                 </Text>
                <LineChart
                    data={{
                        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [
                                Math.random() * 100,
                                Math.random() * 100,
                                Math.random() * 100,
                                Math.random() * 100,
                                Math.random() * 100,
                                Math.random() * 100
                            ]
                        }]
                    }}
                    width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // from react-native
                    height={220}
                    yAxisLabel={'$'}
                    chartConfig={{
                        backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
                        backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
                        backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
                        decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                        style: {
                            borderRadius: 16
                        }
                    }}
                    bezier
                    style={{
                        marginVertical: 8,
                        borderRadius: 16
                    }}
                />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

I hope someaone can help me ! Thank you